# How could I create different interceptors for different API-endpoints?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor

I have 2 **Services** in **AngularJS** that for *2 different* **API-endpoints**, they are based on **$http** service (or simply they are wrappers of $http).

Now I have task to create errorHandling for each of the services. What is the best way to do it in Angular?

pseudo code:

```
angular.service('api1', function($http){ ... });
angular.service('api2', function($http){ ... });
```

Comment: How you want handle errors and what kind of errors?

Comment: all error that are going to *http error* callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 solutions:

1. Just create ErrorHandling service and inject it into both services

.

```
 angular.service('api1', function($http, ErrorHandlingService){ ... });
 angular.service('api2', function($http, ErrorHandlingService){ ... });
```

2. To use interceptor for $http and handle all the requests:

.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(ErrorHandlingService);
```